# Detecting water in a plant stem in real time using computer vision (OpenCV and Python)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on an experiment with plants in a pressure chamber. I need to be able to identify with a computer vision algorithm the exact moment when water starts to appear at the cut end of the stem. In the case of [this video](https://youtu.be/5VD3qlcJLlc) - taken from a USB microscope, this is the interval between 0:30 and 0:34 seconds, approximately.
I tried to use MOG, MOG2 and GMG as a background subtractor, and compare the histograms of each frame (using chi-squared, bhattacharyya, correlation), looking for changes that could be significant, however still without success. Is there a better alternative for this type of work?
Below, some code (made with the help of a friend)

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import time
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
video_filename = 'M20201022_004.mov'
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(video_filename)
#fgbg = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
#kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3,3))
#fgbg = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorGMG()

width = int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
frames_per_second = capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
num_frames = int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print(' height: {}\n width: {}\n fps: {}\n num_frames: {}\n'.format(height, width,frames_per_second, num_frames))

frameCounter = 0
t = time.process_time()
dist_hist = 0 # distance between histograms
frame_hist = 0
time_hist = 0
#write file
file1 = open("resultado.txt","w") 
if not capture.isOpened():
    print("Could not open video")
    print('frameCounter: {}'.format(frameCounter))
    sys.exit(1)

while capture.isOpened():
  success, frame = capture.read()
  frameCounter += 1
  # Test for read error
  if not success:
      print('Failed to read video - Video Capture EOF or Error')
      print('frameCounter:{}'.format(frameCounter))
      if frameCounter == num_frames + 1:
          print('EOF found')
      else:
          print('error')
      break      
      #sys.exit(1)
  else:           
      if frameCounter % 1000 == 0:
          print('type:{} size:{} dtype:{} len(shape):{} contador:{}'.format(type(frame),frame.size,frame.dtype,len(frame.shape),frameCounter))

          if len(frame.shape) < 3:  # grayscale
              h, w = frame.shape
              print('h:{} w:{}'.format(h, w))
          else:                     # color image
              h, w, ch = frame.shape
              print('h:{} w:{} ch:{}'.format(h, w, ch))


      fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
      #fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
      #fgmask = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
      # Initial histogram Test
      if frameCounter == 1:
          hist_initial = cv2.calcHist([fgmask], [0],None,[16],[0, 256])
      #  print('hist_initial:{}'.format(hist_initial))
      #elapsed_time = time.process_time() - t
      elapsed_time = frameCounter / frames_per_second
      # Process Histogram  
      hist_process = cv2.calcHist([fgmask], [0],None,[16],[0, 256])
     
      dist = cv2.compareHist(hist_initial, hist_process,cv2.HISTCMP_CHISQR)

      str1 = str(frameCounter) + "," + str(dist) + "," + str(dist_hist) + "," + str(elapsed_time)
      file1.write(str1)
      file1.write("\n") 

      if dist > dist_hist:    # Depending on compareHist method 
            dist_hist = dist
            time_hist = elapsed_time
            frame_hist = frameCounter

      # Print line at image
      strfmt = 'frame: {} elapsed_time: {:7.2f}'.format(frameCounter, elapsed_time) 

      cv2.putText(frame, strfmt, (0, 50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0,0,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
      cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
      cv2.imshow('fgmask', fgmask)
      if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == 27:  # ESC pressed
          break

print('---> frame:{} dist:{:10.6f} time:{:7.2f}'.format(frame_hist, dist_hist,time_hist))
capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
file1.close()
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: As you know, water is essentially transparent, so that "seeing" it is somewhat desperate and image processing will not help you. Try with very different viewing/illumination angles to see reflection instead of water, or a sudden change in reflexivity of the surface (though in this microscope setup I doubt you have much freedom.

Comment: @Yves Daoust, this microscope has 8 LEDs, and if I could detect the reflection of that luminosity in the water, it might help too. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I would crop down to the region of interest & use a straight forward thershold as there does appear to be a change in grayscale values when the water arrives.